# Are sinners in Satan's kingdom?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, soteriology, satan, sacrifice

OK, people seem to agree who is in Christ's kingdom. But if there is a Satan's kingdom. Are non-Christians or sinners part of his kingdom? what does that say about rich evil politicians? Does the bible say who is in his kingdom? Is it ethical to say?

Reading Matthew 12:26

If Satan drives out Satan, he is divided against himself. How then can his kingdom stand?

just want to know what the bible says so I warn myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**Luke 11:23** (NASB)](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/luke/passage.aspx?q=luke+11:18-28)
>   "He who is not with Me is against Me; and he who does not gather with Me, scatters."
>
> [**Mark 9:40** (NASB)](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/mark/passage.aspx?q=mark+9:35-45)
>   "For he who is not against us is for us."

There appear to be only two camps.

Though Satan's "kingdom" is not given a thorough treatment in the text, any kingdom that is not God's kingdom cannot prevail against God and is unavoidably doomed.

Declaring another human to be in Satan's kingdom is probably overstepping our bounds. Short of being given a prophetic word, we are not granted the (knowledge or) authority to judge another human's eternal destiny. That is the prerogative of deity who knows the depths of the heart. ([2 Ti 4:1, 8](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/2-timothy/passage.aspx?q=2-timothy+4:1-13), [He 12:28](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/hebrews/passage.aspx?q=hebrews+12:18-28))